# ChildClass cannot access to new value of ParentClass' member variable

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a problem with inheritance in Python.I have changed the member variable of ParentClass by itself.The problem is ChildClass cannot access to new value of ParentClass' member variable.
Please look at this simple example:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = "Tommy"

    def changeParentName(self):

        self.name = "Jack"


class Child(Parent):

    def parentName(self):

        print self.name    

parent = Parent()
parent.changeParentName()
child = Child()
child.parentName()
```

If you try above example, you'll see this result:

```
Tommy
```

But i expect to see Jack instead of Tommy.
I have this problem with Python 2.7.9
Can anyone explain this problem or give us a solution?
Does ChildClass call ParentClass' Constructor? so self.name equals Tommy again.
Actually, i have this problem in my project, But i have explained my problem with above example

Comment: you need to read more about inheritance, classes and instances in general, your misunderstanding has nothing to do with python.

Comment: I never blame python programming language. that's my misunderstanding. i should study more about OOP.

Answer (score 0):

The two objects have nothing to do with each other.

```
>>> parent = Parent()
>>> parent.name
'Tommy'
>>> parent.changeParentName()
>>> parent.name
'Jack'

>>> child = Child()
>>> child.name
'Tommy'
>>> child.changeParentName()
>>> child.name
'Jack'
```

When you declare you class `Child` you are establishing *inheritance*.

```
class Child(Parent):
```

This means `Child` *is a* `Parent`. It does not mean that `Parent` *has a* `Child`.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847727/python-inheritance-versus-composition) that discusses Inheritance vs Composition.

Comment: many thanks for answer. i understood.  i think that my question was weird.