# How to extend a class, only if it exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, try-catch

I'm building some code from a stylesheet, but I also want to have the ability to add a custom class in python. However, sometimes, the custom class won't exist. For example, I have two classes: `foo_base`, and `foo_custom`. I want to define a class `foo` that can extend both classes, or just `foo_base` if `foo_custom` doesn't exist

```py
try:
    def foo(foo_base, foo_custom):
except:
    def foo(foo_base):
...
        def __init__(self):
            ...
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Essentially, I want to extend the class if it exists.

Thanks!

Comment: How does your module determine/add `foo_custom` into place? What I mean is do you have an import statement of some kind?

Comment: You can extend a class, only if exists in any language. This is referred to as Inheritence in OOP. Please refer following link, to get more insight.https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Comment: Agreed with @metatoaster that it needs import statement at the top of your code snippet.

Comment: Are the `def foo(...)` statements in your code supposed to be `class foo(...)` statements?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an exception of some kind for handling just two case, the parent class argument in the type constructor (i.e. `class` statement) allow the argument expansion of a list in Python 3.  Such that what you could do for example is:

```
parent_classes = [MainParent]

# it is also possible to make use of `importlib` to go through a
# list of possible imports rather than doing this one-by-one in
# this verbose manner
try:
    from might_be_missing import SomeOtherClass
except ImportError:
    pass  # perhaps log a warning of some kind
else:
    parent_classes.append(SomeOtherClass)

# To create the class

class YourClass(*parent_classes):
    """
    The main class definition
    """
```

However, this particular pattern is typically not a useful pattern for the ultimate end-users of this class necessarily, because this doesn't provide a stable behavior that users can easily infer given that this is stuck behind a system they may not necessarily have control over.  A more useful technique over class inheritance could be [class composition](https://codefellows.github.io/sea-python-401d4/lectures/inheritance_v_composition.html) for the [problem you might be actually solving](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Please also see: [Python: Inheritance versus Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847727/python-inheritance-versus-composition)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a registry to register your classes, and then check the registry to see if it exists.

```py
class Registry(): #Creating Registry class

   def __init__(self):
      self.registry = []

   def register(self,class_):
      self.registry.append(class_) 
      return class_

   def check(self, class_):
       if class_ in self.registry:
           return True

registry = Registry()  #Creating Registry object

@registry.register  #Adding to the Registry
class Some():
     pass
Some()  #Creating class instance
print(registry.check(Some))  #Checking if it exists
#Output
#True
```

Then its just a matter of calling

````py
if registry.check(your_class):
   #Do something```
````